# massive join does not use indexes

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table tbl_ratings with about 100 million records. Each record is a rating by a user on an item. Think of it as whole bunch of item vectors, with each vector containing a rating at some user_id dimensions. My goal is to compute the average difference between every pair of vectors (on matching dimensions). I am trying to do it with join onto itself, but for some reason it is ignoring both of my indexes.

```
CREATE TABLE    tbl_ratings
(
     user_id    MEDIUMINT   UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
     item_id    MEDIUMINT   UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
     rating     TINYINT              NOT NULL,
     UNIQUE KEY user_index (user_id,item_id,rating) USING HASH,
     UNIQUE KEY item_index (item_id,user_id,rating) USING HASH
) ENGINE=MEMORY;

EXPLAIN
SELECT      a.item_id                   as active_id,
            n.item_id                   as neighbor_id,
            AVG(a.rating-n.rating)      as intercept,
            COUNT(a.rating)             as overlap
FROM        tbl_ratings                 as a # active vectors
JOIN        tbl_ratings                 as n # neighbor vectors
ON          a.user_id=n.user_id
GROUP BY    a.item_id, n.item_id \G

*************************** 1. row ***************************
id           : 1
select_type  : SIMPLE
table        : a
type         : ALL
possible_keys: user_index
key          : NULL
key_len      : NULL
ref          : NULL
rows         : 100480507
Extra        : Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
id           : 1
select_type  : SIMPLE
table        : n
type         : ALL
possible_keys: user_index
key          : NULL
key_len      : NULL
ref          : NULL
rows         : 100480507
Extra        : Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, a hash index cannot be used for range lookups, which is what you are doing by only comparing against part of the composite key.

Comment: You're right, according to "High Performance MySQL: Optimization, Backups, and Replication" hash indexes do not support partial key matching. Still, are there any other suggestions, besides changing index types?

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, either change to a BTree index (of which the user_id is the first field, so all entries for a user will cluster together), or use a non-unique hash index on just the user_id join field. There is no other option.